# ALTER COLUMN token TYPE varchar('800');

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to convert that '800'(String) to 800(Integer)

I had use

```
ALTER COLUMN token TYPE varchar('800'::integer)
```

or

```
ALTER COLUMN token TYPE varchar(CAST('800' as integer))
```

but still not working

Please help, thanks

Comment: Do you have a varchar column where you store integer values? And now you want to alter the column data type to integer?

Comment: @jarlh that's not I mean, I want to convert that '800' because it sends from the input and it can't be string when I run, it has to be integer 800.

Comment: Can you show some more code around this? How do you get that 800 value and how are you injecting it into that ALTER COLUMN command? I doubt that you can use variables there

Comment: @HansKeﬆing no more code, I just want to convert that '800', and you right, '800' value is from the input variable. FYI Im using Software AG to manipulate to Postgre, but thats not the point and nothing difference.

Comment: If you don't want to alter the type of the column and just want to cast the string to an integer why not?: `select '800'::int;  800`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver but how to implement in this case to convert that '800' to 800 ? ALTER COLUMN token TYPE varchar('800');

Comment: Do you mean you want to `INSERT` the character string `'800'` into an integer column?

Comment: You are trying to do dynamic SQL and that is not always straight forward for DDL statements. See my answer for some suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of suggestions based on:

```
create table t (fld_1 varchar);
 \d t
                      Table "public.t"
 Column |       Type        | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+-------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 fld_1  | character varying |           |          |
```

In `psql`:

```
\set type_length '10'
alter table t alter COLUMN fld_1 type varchar(:type_length);
ALTER TABLE

\d t
                        Table "public.t"
 Column |         Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 fld_1  | character varying(10) |           |          |
```

Using `plpgsql`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.type_change(type_length character varying)
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
    execute format('alter table t alter COLUMN fld_1 type varchar(%s)', type_length);
RETURN;
END;
$function$

select type_change('50');
 type_change 
-------------
 
 \d t
                        Table "public.t"
 Column |         Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 fld_1  | character varying(50) |           |          |
```

You could expand the above to take the table and column names to make it more generic.

Of course another option is to build the query dynamically in whatever client/language you are using to interact with the database.

Comment: You're my hero man, big thanks!